# In MySQL how to return a count of records where the SUM of two colmuns in related tables is equal to a particular value?

Tags: mysql, sum, aggregate, having

Say I have the following 3 tables:
Table 1 (Sessions)

```
SessionID SessionName
1         Running
2         Jumping
3         Skipping
4         Running
5         Running
```

Table 2 (Bookings)

```
ID SessionID UserID Attended
1  1         1      1
2  4         2      1
3  4         3      0
4  2         1      1
5  5         4      1
```

Table 3 (OtherBookings)

```
ID SessionID GroupID NumberAttended
1  1         1       1
2  1         2       32
3  2         1       4
4  4         3       3
5  4         4       1
```

I want find the count of session where the Session Name is 'Running' and the sum of the attendees (from the other two tables is greater than a given value, say 5). So something like:

SELECT COUNT(*) AS SessionTotal 
... 
HAVING SUM(Bookings.Attended + OtherBookings.NumberAttended) > 5

Comment: What would the desired result look like?

Comment: So I would would simply want the count of sessions (e.g. 10) as my result where I have specified the Session Name e.g. Running and also specified the attended amount threshold e.g. > 10 (which needs to be calculated from the Bookings and OtherBookings tables) - hope that makes sense.

Comment: This is fun. So what would the desired result look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would that work?

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM   sessions s 
WHERE  IFNULL((SELECT sum(b.attended) FROM bookings b WHERE b.sessionid = 
           s.sessionid AND s.sessionname = 'Running'), 0) 
       + 
       IFNULL((SELECT sum(o.numberattended) FROM otherbookings o WHERE 
           o.sessionid = s.sessionid AND s.sessionname = 'Running'), 0) 
       > 5;
```

Here is [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ae5b6/2).

This query counts sum for two tables separately in subqueries and then adds results together. `IFNULL` is there to handle a case when one of the subqueries returns `null`.